# Sanitize characters on MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql

I have a text field in a table that looks like this:

> Brand New Floor Plan – this “Sandpiper” twin villa condo features 2
>   bedrooms, 2 ½ baths and den & 8’ interior doors.

When I display these on a webpage I get really strange characters where the " and ' occur like this: �

I"m able to clean the double quotes fine like this:

```
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '“', '"');
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '”', '"');
```

Causes error:

```
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '’', ''');
```

> ERROR: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '''')' at line 1

I think the issue is using single quotes three times in a row '''

How do I sanitize the single quotes?

Comment: This is an encoding problem...somewhere.  Either your MySQL encoding can't handle curly quotes, and it's replacing them with smiley faces, or maybe you need to HTML encode things before sending to the web browser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your error 1064 you should escape your quote character with a backslash :

```
UPDATE RESI SET MarketingRemarks = REPLACE(MarketingRemarks, '’', '\'');
```

---

To fix your issue of characters not appearing in your webpage, you should manage the encoding properly, which basically requires 3 things :

A. Ideally your table should have a utf8 encoding.

B. in the code behind your webpage, you should tell the database that you want utf8 encoding. For instance in PHP with mysqli :

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

C. you should specify utf8 encoding in the html header of the page :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can load the "wrong values" from database and get them shown correctly in Java, you should then try to escape somehow like this:

https://coderwall.com/p/rvduyw/jdbc-inserting-unicode-utf-8-characters-into-mysql

And update the row with the new value. This should fix it.

Comment: Updated question, check it out.